# react es6 fetch one by one

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, fetch

I have following React codes:

```
fetchA() {
  fetch(aURL)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      this.setState({ a: json})
    })
}

fetchB() {
  fetch(bURL)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      this.setState({ b: json})
    })
}
```

Most tutorials in the web teach you how to `wait until responses of both A and B been collected` such as:

```
Promise.all([fetchA, fetchB])
  .then(values => {
    console.log(values[0])
    console.log(values[1])
  })
```

But what I want is `fetch A, when A finished<results been colleted> then fetch B`.

How could I do that?

Thanks for your time!

====== edited =======

In my real codes, I tried with:

```
fetchA(){
  fetch(aURL)
    .then(fetchB())
    .then(response => console.log(response))
    .then(() => console.log('hi'))
}

fetchB(){
  fetch(bURL)
    .then((response) => console.log(response))
}

// call it
this.fetchA()

// output:
//
// A data
// hi
// B data

// what I want is:
// 
// B data
// A data
// hi
```

Comment: *"But what I want is fetch A, when A finished<results been colleted> then fetch B."* if you skip over the `when` in that statement, you have essentially the text version of the code you need to write. The methods and order are even very close. **just don't forget to return from fetchA and fetchB.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `then` to chain it.

```
fetch(aURL)
    .then(response = > console.log('do something'))
    .then(fetchB)
```

**Update:** don't forget to correct `fetchB`. It should return `Promise`.

```
fetchB() {
  return fetch(bURL)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      this.setState({ b: json})
    })
}
```

Comment: if all I have is fetchB and fetchA it's OK. But what if I have fetchC?  e.g.: `fetch(aURL).then(()=>console.log('a')).then(fetchB()).then(fetchC())` won't guarantee `fetchB()` been executed before `fetchC()`, right?

Comment: @mCY why are you adding `()`? if you removed it, the answer to your comment would be, no, it would guarentee said order.

Comment: @Kevin B but I tried with `fetch(aURL).then(res => console.log(res)).then(fetchB).then(()=> console.log('hi'))`. But `hi` comes before fetchB's output ...

Comment: @mCY probably because fetchB is coded incorrectly. did you forget to return a promise?

Comment: @Kevin B, plus, I found out adding`()` or not doesn't change the order. `fetchB()` returns a Promise, `fetchB` returns a function? But why remove the `()` ?

Comment: ... because that executes fetch b, you want to only execute fetch b once a is complete. In your question, fetchA and fetchB return nothing, which makes it nearly impossible to control the order in which things run.

Comment: It's literally as simple as `fetchA().then(fetchB)` if your fetches are coded properly.

Comment: @KevinB and @Stanislav Mayorov, thanks guys. I think I understand. firstly no `()` cause `then` accept function not result. secondly, it's simply fetchA().then(fetchB).then(fetchC).then ... Don't know why I just confused... Maybe I wrongly added `()` makes the output wrong. Thanks!

Comment: @KevinB, I thought I understand it. but no... I asked another question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44185921/react-fetch-sequently. Where i'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
fetchA() {
  fetch(aURL)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
       this.setState({ a: json}, this.fetchB); //this line changed
    })
}
```

and call `this.fetchA()` to start