# fetch sequently

Tags: ecmascript-6, fetch

Codes are as following:

```
var fetch = require('node-fetch')

function fetchA(){
  fetch('https://github.com/keegoo')
    .then(response => console.log('fetchA'))
    .then(fetchB)
    .then(fetchC)
    .then(() => console.log('hi'))
}

function fetchB(){
  fetch('https://github.com/keegoo/trigger')
    .then(response => console.log('fetchB'))
}

function fetchC(){
  fetch('https://github.com/keegoo/trigger/tree/master/app')
    .then(response => console.log('fetchC'))

}
// call 
fetchA()
```

Inside fetchA, I called fetchB and fetchC.

I'm expecting the output should be:

```
fetchA
fetchB
fetchC
hi
```

instead, it's:

```
fetchA
hi
fetchC
fetchB
```

Why?

If I need the output to be `fetchA -> fetchB -> fetchC -> Hi`, what should I do?

Comment: you're still not returning the promise generated by calling fetch.

Comment: `fetch` has nothing to do with React: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fetchB` and `fetchC` should return the promises from `fetch`, otherwise the subsequent calls like `.then(fetchB)` are resolved immediately.

```
function fetchB(){
  return fetch('https://github.com/keegoo/trigger')
    .then(response => console.log('fetchB'))
}

function fetchC(){
  return fetch('https://github.com/keegoo/trigger/tree/master/app')
    .then(response => console.log('fetchC'))
}
```

Comment: @KevinB and @Sheng, I understand without this `return fetch...`, it will resolve immediately. but why with it, everything's different? How it handled this return inside `.then()`?

Comment: @mCY: `.then()` returns a promise (A). That promise resolves to the return value of the callback passed to it, if that values is a "normal" value. But if the value is another promise (B), then promise A will be "chained" to promise B, resolving to whatever B resolves to.

Comment: @mCY ``fetch`` function returns Promise because it's async request.

Comment: Thanks, that's really help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to **return promise** !!!

You need to know following two facts before understanding the reason.

1. return value of a promise(`then` here) will be passed to the next promise(next `then`).

```js
Promise.resolve('A')
  .then(x => {
    console.log(x)  // output A
    return 'B'
  }) 
  .then(x => {
    console.log(x)  // output B
                    // no return here !
  })
  .then(x => {
    console.log(x)  // output undefined, cause the **previous** `then` didn't return anything
    return 'C' 
  })
  .then(x => {
    console.log(x)  // output C
    return 'D'
  })// promise chain goes on ...
```

2. a promise chain, e.g. `fetch().then().then().then()`..., will return immediately.

```js
// here blockA simulate a heavy operation: 3000 ms later, 'A' will be returned.
const blockA = new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve('A'), 3000))

blockA
.then(x => {
  console.log(x)
  return 'B'
})
.then(x => {
  console.log(x)
  return 'c'
}) // chains goes on ...

console.log('Hello world')
```

No matter how long the promise chain is, 'Hello world' always output first, which means the promise chain returned immediately. Until `blockA` been resolved sometime later, the following `then`s will be executed(callback).

In your case:

`fetchB` and `fetchC` will return immediately, right?

```
function fetchA(){
  fetch('https://github.com/keegoo')
    .then(response => console.log('fetchA'))  // when 'https://...' responded, this promise been execute, output fetchA
    .then(fetchB)   // then fetchB be executed, but return immediately.
    .then(fetchC)   // then fetchC be executed, but return immedidately again.
    .then(() => console.log('hi'))  // then output 'hi'
}

// sometime in the future, when the `fetch`s inside fetchB and fetchC got responses, the `console.log`s then be executed.
```

So if you `return fetch().then().then()`, the promise chain will be bought to the next promise, and will be resolved fully before moving on.